# Django - dumpdata truncate to last n lines

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, mysql

Does anyone have a simple solution to using (or modifying) dumpdata to trucate a simple table down to the last n lines.  I like to use dump data for test fixtures but the data size has gotten so large this doesn't make sense.  BTW - I didn't design the table I'm just the sucker which has to deal with it.

For those who may ask how the structure looks here it is.

From Django Side

```
class GridResourceUsage(models.Model):
    """Sampled point in time of license usage for individual grid resource. Includes who and quanity."""
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True)
    grid_license_resource = models.ForeignKey(GridLicResource)
    total    = models.IntegerField(default=None, null=True)
    limit    = models.IntegerField(default=None, null=True)
    free     = models.IntegerField(default=None, null=True)
    intern   = models.IntegerField(default=None, null=True)
    extern   = models.IntegerField(default=None, null=True)
    waiting  = models.IntegerField(default=None, null=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return str("GRU-" + self.grid_license_resource.name) 
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-timestamp']
    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return('hist_res_id', (), {'resource': str(self.grid_license_resource.name), 'id':str(self.id)})
```

From MySQL side

```
CREATE TABLE `gridresource_gridresourceusage` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `timestamp` datetime NOT NULL,
  `grid_license_resource_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `total` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `limit` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `free` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `intern` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `extern` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `waiting` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `gridresource_gridresourceusage_timestamp` (`timestamp`),
  KEY `gridresource_gridresourceusage_grid_license_resource_id` (`grid_license_resource_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2891167 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure if `dumpdata` can do what you ask for.

Can't you just create a queryset and [serialize](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/) it? A bit silly example but it should work.

```
# Create queryset you want
n = SomeModel.objects.count()-1 # Row offset counting from the end
queryset = SomeModel.objects.all()[n:]

# Serialize that queryset to json in this case
from django.core import serializers
data = serializers.serialize("json", queryset)

# And write it into the file
f = open('data.json', 'w')
f.write(data)
f.close()
```

You can wrap this up in [management command](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/#writing-custom-django-admin-commands) and use it more or less the same way you are using the `dumpdata` command. (You could also look at source of [dumpdata](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/core/management/commands/dumpdata.py) for ideas)